# JS - Why does the order of this if/else matter?

Tags: javascript

Why would this not work if I took the first "if" statement and put it as the third "else if" statement? Just want to understand. Thanks!

```
function fizzBuzz(num) {

  if ((num % 3 === 0) && (num % 5 === 0)) {
    return 'fizzbuzz';
  } else if (num % 3 === 0) {
    return 'fizz';
  } else if (num % 5 === 0) {
    return 'buzz';
  } else {
    return num;
  }

  // if num is divisible by 3 return 'fizz'
  // if num is divisible by 5 return 'buzz'
  // if num is divisible by 3 & 5 return 'fizzbuzz'
  // otherwise return num
}
```

Comment: Because one of the other if statements would evaluate to true  before hitting that else if

Comment: Can you add more details to the code like what inputs num are you testing this with, for which num it works but after changing the order of if it doesn't?

Comment: because like in real life. IF you have water AND IF you have glass, drink water from glass. ELSE IF you only have water, water some plants. ELSE IF you only have a glass, Break it and make a collage. FInally, if you do not have water nor glass, go shopping...

Comment: In the first `if`, you check for two conditions to be true at the same time (A & B are true). In the latter two, you check for those two conditions individually (A true? then B true?). If you swap the order, one of (A true?) or (B true?) will be entered but no other if else branch will be.

Comment: Just use ternarys here. That can be solved in a one liner... ;)

Answer (score 2):

If-else-if statement only work until one of the if statements becomes true.

This scenario prevents to check other "else if" conditions.
In your second scenario if modulus of "num" is 0 for 3 OR 5, it will stop checking other else if statements,

It is necessary to prioritize the sequence of if-else-if conditions.

Answer (score 1):

Yes Remember that if/else-if/else executes in order and will stop when it finds an acceptable case. In your example, if `(num % 3 === 0)` you'll return return 'fizz' and that condition is true. So This is (num % 5 === 0) and (num % 3 === 0) && (num % 5 === 0)) are not mutually exclusive - they can both be true, so the order matters.

Answer (score 1):

So a if/else if statement works so that as soon as one of the ifs is true, it executes the code inside  that if statement and then skips the rest of the ifs and else statements. In this case, however, the return ends the function and therefore it skips the rest of the code in the method.

Answer (score 1):

If else if checks each condition on by one. If any of the conditional blocks executes, the rest of the conditions won't work.

```
function fizzBuzz(num) {

  if ((num % 3 === 0) && (num % 5 === 0)) {
    return 'fizzbuzz';
  } else if (num % 3 === 0) {
    return 'fizz';
  } else if (num % 5 === 0) {
    return 'buzz';
  } else {
    return num;
  }

  // if num is divisible by 3 return 'fizz'
  // if num is divisible by 5 return 'buzz'
  // if num is divisible by 3 & 5 return 'fizzbuzz'
  // otherwise return num
}
```

In your example, if you put the first condition in the third block, i.e, `else if`, if the number is divisible by either 3 or, 5, the corresponding conditional block work and resulting in skipping the third block. The order of execution is important in `if-else-if` ladder.